# To send notification mail to the users when an item in the sharepoint list is not updated

Tags: list

I have a SharePoint list in which each item has fields for updating the weekly status. By the end of every week, I want to send a notification to the users who have not yet updated the item (particual field is blank). The user name is availble in a field in each item. Kindly let me know how I can get this done using SharePoint.

Comment: You need to write a programa in C# to detect items not updated and send and email. Youn cannot solve this requeriment with configuration.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a SharePoint Designer workflow. You can a workflow instance for each item. This workflow's logic would look something like this:

```
Stage 1
Pause for 7 days
Transition to Stage 2

Stage 2
If FIELD is empty
 Send Email
Else
 Log "Field is set to %FIELDVALUE"
Transition to Stage 1
```